# Customize local notification in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, unnotificationattachment

How to create [this type](http://prntscr.com/g2dpla) of local notification in objective-c.

Comment: Please put some code. So, answerer can know which effort you made for it.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/g2ds2r
i am able to create local notification like this...I want to know how can i customize its UI.

Comment: You can see Swift code into following tutorial. You need to manage it for Objective-c.
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-10-creating-custom-notification-interfaces--cms-27251

Comment: Thanks...i will check.

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you are setting up a local notification and you're just interested in having an image show up in the notification itself, you don't have to bother with NotificationsUI.framework

```
UNMutableNotificationContent *content = [UNMutableNotificationContent new];
    content.title = @"Title";
    content.body = @"Body";
    content.sound = [UNNotificationSound defaultSound];
    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"file:/some/path/in/app/image.png"];
    NSError *error;
    UNNotificationAttachment *icon = [UNNotificationAttachment attachmentWithIdentifier:@"image" URL:imageURL options:nil error:&error];
    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"error while storing image attachment in notification: %@", error);
    }
    if (icon)
    {
        content.attachments = @[icon];
    }
```

Then when the notification appears, the image will show up on the right-hand side of the notification banner like it does for Messages notifications. And you don't have to jump through all of the hoops of setting up a content extension with a categoryIdentifier, etc.

Comment: Actually my requirement was to show the notification as shown in the attached image.